# Postman oAuth2 error Unauthorized grant type

Tags: java, postman, oauth-2.0

I have an application that use oAuth2, and I try to request an access token from terminal with this command

```
curl -X POST -vu clientapp:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=spring&username=roy&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write&client_secret=123456&client_id=clientapp"
```

it works fine and I get a response like this

```
{"access_token":"29c4c218-1d9a-4d2d-abe3-197bc2969679","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"6b7ffda7-4652-4197-b8e9-c80635eb9143","expires_in":38630,"scope":"read write"}
```

but the problem is when I try to request an access token via postman is always get this error:

```
Handling error: InvalidClientException, Unauthorized grant type: client_credentials
```

how do get access token via postman like I get token via curl command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the attached image, you need to pass like below .

And in header you also need to pass Authorization header.

`Authorization`  -->  `Basic Y2xpZW50OnNlY3JldA==`

[image]

This will work for me , I hope this will help you .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion and it work for me too, but I want to do it with Authorization OAuth 2.0 from postman to generate the header. is it possible? @Parth Solanki

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @AshishKumarMondal wc

Answer (score 3):

Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

In the body, Just select x-www-form-urlencoded and then provide the grant_type and client_credentials in the as key value pair.